# Why does gearman-job-server not accept connections when running as a service?

Tags: ubuntu, services

On Ubuntu 12.04, If I run `sudo gearmand -d`, the manager will accept jobs from remote machines.
However, if I run `sudo service start gearman-job-server` (after killing gearmand), remote connections are refused.

Where should I look for why this is happening and / or how can I resolve it?

Gearman version is 1.0.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that the gearman-job-server **service** starts up with the following parameters by default on Ubuntu:

```
PARAMS="--listen=127.0.0.1"
```

as defined in `/etc/default/gearman-job-server`

Changing this to `PARAMS=""` resolves the remote connection problem though you would probably want to investigate http://gearman.org/manual/job_server/#options to configure gearman to your needs

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 you have to change the parameters in:

```
/lib/systemd/system/gearman-job-server.service
```

Slightly more precise answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/239104/134199).

Answer (score -1):

> sudo nano /etc/default/gearman-job-server

change params

> PARAMS="--listen=0.0.0.0"
>
> sudo service gearman-job-server restart