# How can I get gearmand to accept remote connections?

Tags: ubuntu

I see this question:
[Why does gearman-job-server not accept connections when running as a service?](https://superuser.com/questions/728947/why-does-gearman-job-server-not-accept-connections-when-running-as-a-service)
but there is no config file in my gearman installation on Ubuntu (or at least not one that I can find).  I'm using gearman 1.1.12

I also tried to start gearman like...
`sudo gearmand -l gearmand.log --listen="*"`
and no luck

Worth noting that I installed from source.  This does not happen when I install from the package but it's still probably worth getting an answer on as installing from source is valuable to get the latest and greatest

Answer (score 0):

Gearman's config file is a bit hidden under Ubuntu: Take a look at `/etc/default/gearman-job-server`.

Adding `PARAMS="--listen=127.0.0.1"` will listen on localhost, while `PARAMS="--listen=192.168.xxx.yyy"` might be what you want.

Comment: That file didn't exist.  Do you think that is problematic?  I created it and added `PARAMS=""` but it still doesn't seem to accept remote connections.